# Accessing objects using NSPointerArray?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, casting, nspointerarray

I have an `NSPointerArray` and in one of my methods, I want to access the objects stored in that `NSPointerArray` (as I have to use one of the object's `properties`). I don't want to create a new `NSArray` with the allObjects method as that will be redundant in my program. Right now, I'm doing the following which uses a lot of `memory`? (Sorry, I'm a noob).

```
-(void) print
{
    for (int i=0; i<[list count]; i++){
        NSLog(@"%@",[((__bridge Song*)[list pointerAtIndex: i])  title]);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would this use a lot of memory? This seems like the most economical way of doing what you need (in terms of memory use) because no new objects get created.

Comment: I was a little doubtful about that. But now I got it. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your problem is already solved. Wanted to mention its easier to loop over your `NSPointerArray` with a `foreach` loop. In this case you do it like this:

```
-(void) print {
    for (Song *s in list){
        NSLog(@"%@", [s title]);
    }
}
```

This way you can concentrate on the object instead of using the `integer` of your loop.

Comment: `NSPointerArray` does not support `NSEnumeration` nor `NSFastEnumeration`. Therefore you cannot iterate using the `for(... in ...)` syntax.

Comment: NSPointerArray does not conform to sequence

Comment: NSPointer now conforms to NSFastEnumeration https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspointerarray